# Reverse engineer a string masking/obfuscating function

Tags: encryption, reverse-engineering

I would like to unmask or unobfuscate a piece of base64 encoded string containing some characters.

For instance, I know `VovL5SaV_iSBx6oAFGypsTCO` matches `00000000`. Is there a way, knowing more data (the input and the output) to find out the algorithm that obfuscate the string? I couldn't find anything.

Some example:

- The result of `f(A)` will vary in length if `A` is longer f(A) will be longer, if A is shorter `f(A)` will be shorter.
- If we have A and B with a similar ending (e.g. aaaaa@gmail.com and bbbbb@gmail.com), then f(A) and f(B) will also have the same ending.

Comment: How is this related to base64 ?

Comment: Isn't VovL5SaV_iSBx6oAFGypsTCO a base64 encoded string?

Comment: Yes but it's just a representation of the data, to allow displaying it or transmitting it to systems that are limited to ASCII. Your fundamental question applies to the 18 bytes of arbitrary data behind. If I understand correctly, you have `base64(f("00000000")) = "VovL5SaV_iSBx6oAFGypsTCO"`. So another representation (hexadecimal) is: `hex(f("00000000")) = "568bcbe52695fe2481c7aa00146ca9b1308e"`. You are trying to reverse-engineer `f`. Base64 is irrelevant. And depending on the nature of `f` your question might or might not be about cryptography, it's much too broad, we have no idea.

Comment: @HuguesM. Fair enough, indeed I want to reverse engineer `f`. But it's not about cryptography (see the example I added), it just seems to be about reversible obfuscation.

Comment: Interesting, but also confusing: you said the strings contained numbers, but the new examples are not strings of number characters. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Hum sorry yes, some data contains number only, some contains characters. So let's just treat the whole input as just some characters.

Comment: reverse engineer the application that encodes the strings. Also consider asking reverse engineering questions on [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @SYS_V that's basically my question, how to reverse engineer it. Didn't know there was a stackexchange for that. Thanks :)

Comment: It would help to have more than one input/output example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on what you mentionned, it seems like the encryption uses a block cipher:
One nive property about you block cipher is that the encryption of a block doesn't depend on the one before, this is not allways true, (and is very bad practice=very good for the you the attacker), one of block ciphers that does that is:
ECB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29 , as you can see the same key is used for each encryption, and the block cipher can be equivalent to a XOR allowing to guess decryopt anything. To check that trying f(00000000000000) where the length is more than one block and see if a pattern repeats it self.
If this not the case, you might be useing something like CTR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29 here a "key(i)"=blockcipher(key,nonce(i)) is used to encrypted each block using XOR, if you manage to calculate again f(000000000000) and find key(1), key(2)... you can use them latter to decrypt anything you want. if you can provide me with the tool used for the obfuscation I might be able to decrypt what you want

Comment: The function is basically an API, they use PHP (that's what the server says), and use the decrypted text an output in on image. That's all I know.

Comment: To output an image with the text. It's a simple PHP script that is actually detailed in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php I assume that's what they use.

Comment: the api is a black box (your f function), and you can feed it anything, if yes can I have access to it ?

Answer (score 2):

Given what you said and the comments published, I would say that yes, knowing more data couples `[obfuscated/cleartext]` can help you understand the underlying algorithm.

You will have to analyze various properties, such as string lengths, and characters redundancy, and byte values shift and variations to small changes (eg: changing `000000` to `000001`) Also, control if the obfuscated strings are predictable or repeatable.

Ultimately, try to see if you can forge your own obfuscated texts and see the results. This can be achieved by fuzzing and can help you predict the algorithm in a more aggressive way.

From what you said, I would say this is not a secured block-cypher of the data, but rather a substitution. It could be ROT13 at byte-level or an XOR, both with some padding (metadata?).

Note that the `_` seems to act as a separator: the string as is cannot be decoded, but both parts around the `_` can be.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you with this, but it is illegal under the [United States Digital Millennium copyright act section 1201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/1201). Perhaps somebody in a country with more freedom will respond with a better answer.

```
1201. (1) A. No person shall circumvent a technological measure
that effectively controls access to a work protected under this title.
```